# How to detach from docker container from integrated terminal (send [CTRL + P CTRL + Q]

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm just wondering how to properly detach a running container if it was started from VSCode's integrated terminal?

On a Mac <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> doesn't work.

Comment: Did you try to press CMD+P CMD+Q ?

Comment: On a Mac that would be equivalent to print it and quit :)

Answer (score 20):

Menu under File > Preferences > Keyboard Shortcuts. (Code > Preferences > Keyboard Shortcuts on macOS)

Add `!terminalFocus` to `When` option for <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd>

[image]

Comment: Actually in my case I had to do the upper manipulation but for the "Go to File..." command binded with "ctrl+p"

Comment: Same as @ngazagna, and that I had to (temporarily) change all existing `ctrl+p` and `ctrl+q` key-bindings